# PayPal Return and Cancel URLs not setting properly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, paypal

I'm trying to allow non-PayPal users to be redirected to my website after their purchase. (I understand that they have to click a link to do so). I have my return_url and cancel urls set to the proper urls. The problem is: neither of them redirect properly. instead of http://mywebsite.com/page, it redirects to http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/mypage.

Is there something else I need to set?

I use C# Code to redirect to the webpage. The information such as cost, item name, and merchant info all work and I can make a purchase both with and without paypal. I cannot, however, get back to my website afterwards.

Another Note. Everything WORKS in Sandbox mode, but doesn't in regular.

C# Code (Personal Info Removed):

```
    string redirect;



            redirect = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" + PayPalId;

            redirect += "&item_name=" + "Item Name";
            redirect += "&amount=" + String.Format("{0:0.00} ", cost);



            redirect += "&return=http://mywebsite/success";
            redirect += "&cancel_return=http://mywebsite/cancel";
            Response.Redirect(redirect);
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Take a look at the entire GET request upon redirection to PayPal. You must be missing some part of the URL, or include a non-HTML encoded ampersand within the URL (item name perhaps?) which renders the remainder of the URL 'unreadable'.